# MySQL - explode/split input to stored procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, explode

I have problem, I need to explode my input to my stored procedure, but don't know how I can do it.

My stored procedure has a VARCHAR(256) input which I need to split and generate insert statements.

i what to explode this varchar "1,2,3,7,8,9" so I need to split that string on "," and iterate through the result

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please see [this forum thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,78776,78776) on replicating the functionality in mysql that tsql provides.

That thread also discusses some of the downfalls of this method.  Also, I think you want to be using VARCHAR(255) or just VARCHAR(MAX) because there is no benefit to a 256, it uses a 2 byte size prefix and yet only stores 256 characters.

Have you considered using xml and xpath syntax to extract the values instead?  I think going forward this will become a more readable and  maintainable method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a split_string() function
http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=4

Answer (score 0):

Try my SQL Library: http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/sql/mysql_stored_procedures.texy