# Is there a way to explode a cell value within a mysql statement

Tags: mysql, explode

I have column in table where i store tag ids as 1|5|10

I want to explode the column using mysql query

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742728/mysql-explode-split-input-to-stored-procedure ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably might want to do is **not store your tag ids like this**. Make a **separate table** for them and your problem will dissapear naturally.

That's called [**normalisation**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 2):

You can chain SUBSTRING_INDEX to accomplish an explode effect, but let me remind you this is a horrible solution over database normalisation, as suggested by Kos.

If you were trying to select all MySQL entries with a 5 in your middle column (#|5|#) you would use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(table.field, '|', 2), '|', -1) = 5
```

@Everyone: this is a horrible solution so please don't PLAN to use it; however, some times we're in a situation where a quick one liner like this must be used until a finer inspection on the database schema can happen.