# splitting a column value in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a table which is varray of varchar2. After fetching this column value I want to process each element of this varray column. How to split the retrieved column into individual values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742728/mysql-explode-split-input-to-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id NUMBER, val VARCHAR2(20));
insert into t values (1,'val1');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2,'val2');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'val3');

SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
type my_type IS varray(200) OF VARCHAR2(200);
obj1 my_type := my_type();
BEGIN
     FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
          obj1.extend;
          SELECT val INTO obj1(i) FROM t WHERE id = i;
     end loop;

     FOR j IN obj1.first..obj1.last LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line(obj1(j));
     END LOOP;
END;
```

results:

```
val1
val2
val3
```

or you can use the following folowing for nested table columns:

```
  FOR REC IN
     (SELECT * FROM TABLE(c)    --or  select * from table(cast(c as object_type_tab))
     )
     LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line(rec.id || ', ' || rec.val);
     END LOOP;
```